# How to pass parameters in react-router-dom Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have links to components-pages, for example:

```
<Link to="/"> Home <Link/>
```

In props I have a parameter, for example userId. I need to pass it in Link. I know how to pass params in `onCLick()`:

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/',
  state: {
    userId: 7
  }
})
```

How I understand in ink can be performed `onClick`, but may be it's possible to pass somehow params in it? Without creating `onClick`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an object to the "to" prop like this.

```
 <Link to={{
  pathname: '/courses',
  search: '?sort=name',
  hash: '#the-hash',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
 }}/>
```

Check the documentation for more. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link.

Comment: To get the data passed to the `to` object, you need to use the `useLocation` hook on the next screen.

`let location = useLocation();`